# Create envelope with templateID, role and prefill information for assigned standard and custom fields

Tags: docusignapi

I made below API call to create envelope, it does created a envelope and sent to email address but values for the standard and custom fields are not getting filled.

Receipent needs to add those field values

```
https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2.1/accounts/{accountID}/envelopes

{
  "emailSubject": "This request is sent from a Template",
  "status": "sent",
  "templateId": "{templateID}",
  "templateRoles": [
    {
      "email": "test@test.com",
      "name": "Test User",
      "roleName": "QA",
      "tabs": {
        "dateSignedTabs": [
          {
            "tabLabel": "date",
            "value": "01-01-2024"
          }
        ],
        "fullNameTabs": [
          {
            "tabLabel": "name",
            "value": "Nilesh sawant"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}

Response :

{
  "envelopeId": "{envelopeId}",
  "uri": "/envelopes/{envelopeId}",
  "statusDateTime": "2024-01-03T11:52:09.8070000Z",
  "status": "sent"
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvklW.png)

Answer (score 0):

You did not provide enough information for the tabs. Which document and page or how to position them etc.
The tabs are not part of the template, if they are - it gets more complex as you have to keep the envelope in draft, do a GET to fetch these tabs, then update it with the values. It's easier to just add the tabs and the values in the API call.

Here is an example JSON. You can find the article about this on Dev Center - https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/set-template-tab-values/

```
{
    "customFields": {
        "textCustomFields": [{
            "name": "'"${text_custom_fields["name"]}"'",
            "required": "'"${text_custom_fields["required"]}"'",
            "show": "'"${text_custom_fields["show"]}"'",
            "value": "'"${text_custom_fields["value"]}"'"
        }]
    },
    "status": "Sent",
    "templateId": "'"${template_id}"'",
    "templateRoles": [{
        "clientUserId": "1000",
        "email": "'"${SIGNER_EMAIL}"'",
        "name": "'"${SIGNER_NAME}"'",
        "roleName": "signer",
        "tabs": {
            "checkboxTabs": [{
                "selected": "'"${checkbox_tabs["selected1"]}"'",
                "tabLabel": "'"${checkbox_tabs["tabLabel1"]}"'"
            }, {
                "selected": "'"${checkbox_tabs["selected2"]}"'",
                "tabLabel": "'"${checkbox_tabs["tabLabel2"]}"'"
            }],
            "listTabs": [{
                "documentId": "'"${list_tabs["documentId"]}"'",
                "pageNumber": "'"${list_tabs["pageNumber"]}"'",
                "tabLabel": "'"${list_tabs["tabLabel"]}"'",
                "value": "'"${list_tabs["value"]}"'"
            }],
            "radioGroupTabs": [{
                "groupName": "radio1",
                "radios": [{
                    "selected": "'"${radio_tabs["selected"]}"'",
                    "value": "'"${radio_tabs["value"]}"'"
                }]
            }],
            "textTabs": [{
                "tabLabel": "'"${text_tabs["tabLabel"]}"'",
                "value": "'"${text_tabs["value"]}"'"
            }, {
                "bold": "true",
                "documentId": "1",
                "font": "helvetica",
                "fontSize": "size14",
                "height": "23",
                "locked": "false",
                "pageNumber": "1",
                "required": "false",
                "tabId": "name",
                "tabLabel": "added text field",
                "value": "'"${SIGNER_NAME}"'",
                "width": "84",
                "xPosition": "280",
                "yPosition": "172"
            }]
        }
    }, {
        "email": "'"${CC_EMAIL}"'",
        "name": "'"${CC_NAME}"'",
        "roleName": "cc"
    }]
}
```

Comment: I have created a template in  docusign, assigned few roles to it. Then I have assigned some standard and custom fields (for example, Name, email address, company, title etc) on that template. Now when my app will create an envelope to sent to users then the values for these standard and custom fields should be filled. Which API I should use and how should I sent the values for these standard and custom fields?

Comment: Why do you want the fields to be created on the template and not on the envelope? You can do it, but it requires 3 API calls instead of one

Comment: Our users will be creating fields on template and then those fields will be fetched by our application and values will be set dynamically.

Comment: OK, then what is the reason you want to use a template? Why not just use envelopes directly? What is the benefit the template gives you?

Comment: That is how we are integrating docusign. We will be having list of templates, from that list user will select one templete to send to multiple users. So its standard and custom fields should be filled before envelope ie sent with selected template.

Comment: How do you want the user to specify the fields? do you want them to "tag" the documents and drag and drops fields into it?